# перебор элементов массива на sass

Tags: css, sass

Как перебрать цвета(массив цветов) с помощью sass

```
$color:"#ccc","#caca","#cafa";
@for $i from 1 through length($color){
    .div-#{$i}{
        background:$color{$i};
    }
}
```

// в итоге должно быть что-то типо

```
 .div-1{background:#ccc}
 .div-2{background:#caca}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
$color: "#ccc","#caca","#cafa";
@for $i from 1 through length($color){
    .div-#{$i}{
        background: nth($color, $i);
    }
}
```